# Java JPA Inner join with NULL check

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to execute this JPA query with inner join.

```
 SELECT spost.id 
 FROM Post spost
 INNER JOIN spost.session.students student
 WHERE student.id = :currentUserId
```

The problem is when `spost.session` is NULL. I need to check if `session` is NULL before getting the `students` list and iterating it.

With my coding stucture it's not possible to do it else where. But I have to do it within the JPA query itself.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query like this:

```
SELECT spost.id 
FROM Post spost
INNER JOIN spost.session.students student
WHERE student.id = :currentUserId
AND spost.session is not null
```